# Message "Found 2 elements with non-unique"

Tags: reactjs

The browser says:

> [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #log-in-email;

But I don’t have two elements with a non-unique id.
I searched the whole project, but there wasn't any other element with this id.

What is going on?

Comment: Check the source code of the rendered page in browser and see if somehow same element got rendered twice?

If no, then try changing the id  id #log-in-email to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the source code of the rendered page in the browser and see if somehow the same element got rendered twice.

If not, then try changing the id #log-in-email to something else.